# Rails adds in an extra parameter to the list of parameters on a patch request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, vue.js, axios

I have a vue.js front-end in which I make a PATCH request to the endpoint /stats/:id using axios. Here is the line where I make the request:

```
this.$axios.patch(ApiAddress, { data: this.rows }, {
          headers: { Authorization: this.$requestHeaders.Authorization },
        });
```

Here you can see that the only information that I pass is a key "data" and the "id" key that gets passed via router. But when the controller gets the request I see the following:

{ data => { example: "foo" }, id=>#, stat=>{ data=> { example: "foo" } } }

I dont know where that "stat" parameters is coming from.

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :users
  resources :stats
  mount Knock::Engine => "/knock"

  get "profile/:id", to: 'profile#show', as: 'profile'
  get "profile", to: 'profile#index'
end
```

and this is my stats controller:

```
class StatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def update
    stat = current_user.Stats.find(params[:id])
    # stat.data = params['data']
    param_object = stats_params
    if stat.update(param_object)
      render json: stat
    end
  end

  def stats_params
    params.require(:stat).permit(:data, :title, :privacy)
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :).

Comment: did you check the request's body in browser dev tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intended, and is called `wrap_parameters` in Rails (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html)

To disable that behavior completely, edit `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  - wrap_parameters format: [:json]
  + wrap_parameters format: []
end
```

Or edit your particular controller:

```
class StatsController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters format: []
```